# KILL QUERY Flooding in General Query log for MySQL 8.0.25

Tags: query-performance, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0, kill

**Problem** : We have two MySQL servers in master master replication. We can see many `KILL QUERY` statements in MySQL general log specific to stored procedures as below :

```
2024-03-20T21:54:45.056981+05:30        12996 Query     CALL tc_updatemostinterestedinquiry(9546, 1446507, 3)
2024-03-20T21:54:45.068626+05:30        14167 Connect   stg_abweb_write@10.20.171.33 on autobiz using TCP/IP
2024-03-20T21:54:45.068978+05:30        14167 Query     SET NAMES utf8mb4
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069238+05:30        14167 Query     KILL QUERY 12996
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069497+05:30        14167 Quit
2024-03-20T21:54:45.069586+05:30        12996 Query     DO SLEEP(0)
2024-03-20T21:54:45.070287+05:30        12996 Query     SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

These stored procedures are called from a .NET application where we use dapper library version 1.60.6
`<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.60.6" />`

Stored procedure call syntax in the application is
`con.Connection.Query<dynamic>("stored_procedure_name", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

We use **MysqlConnector** version 1.3.8.

**Findings** :

1. After removing Connection Admin and Super privilege  which is required to run the `KILL QUERY` statement from the MySQL user we observe `KILL QUERY` statements still exists in the general log. You can check about the privileges requirement [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html).
2. This `KILL QUERY` statement creates a new connection every time to the MySQL server for execution.
3. We have read about [MysqlConnector Command Cancellation](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/command-cancellation/) which tells there is a possibility of command timeout. But when we call these stored procedures without any commands in it from the application they still give out `KILL QUERY` in general log. There are no such long running queries in stored procedures.
4. When connecting to MySQL server via workbench and calling same stored procedures we don't face any `KILL QUERY` statements.

We have been facing this problem since quite long, please help.

Comment: This would be better ask on StackOverflow, as it is more about programming